# F# declare variable without instantiating it

Tags: f#, scope, initialization, instantiation, declare

I need to declare a variable in F# without instantiating it. This is simple in C#, but in F#, all I have is the val keyword, and that only works within classes. Is there a way to declare a variable for scope purposes, but to leave the initialization for later?

EDIT: To answer Fyodor's question:

I want to programmatically go through a file folder with C# serialization files, each of which holds an array of either type A or type B objects. Each of these objects has a timestamp, and there is one C# array file per day. So let's pretend there are 20 files in all (10 A files and 10 B files), and within each file, there are 1000 A objects, or 1000 B objects, each object having a timestamp, and each file collecting 1000 data points per day.

The problem is that type A files and type B files are started and stopped at different points throughout the day, so I can't just pick Day1A and Day1B, merge them, then pick Day2A and Day2B, and so on. I need to go through Day1A and Day1B until one of them finishes (say A finishes first), then load Day2A and compare Day2A and Day1B until one of them finishes, ect.

To do this, I need to enumerate over the 1000 objects in each file, as well as the files themselves. I also need to handle weird cases where there are no type A's or type B's left (in which case I just enumerate over the remaining type).

The scope comes into play because I have two sets of enumerators going over two sets of while loops.

Comment: Use a ref cell or a mutable option maybe?

Comment: In C# variables are instantiated implicitly. Primitive types by default values, reference types by null. The null value is not normally used in F#. If a type is defined in F#, null is not permitted as a regular value unless the `AllowNullLiteral` attribute is applied to the type. But you can declare `mutable` values but you have to initialize them explicitly.

Comment: I'm curious: what are those "scope purposes" you speak of? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Sounds like you just need a sequence expression for your A items, and one for B, and then use `Seq.iter2` to compare them both.

Comment: Ok, I guess I simplified it too much. The data is much much more than 20 files x 1000 data points per file. It is in the billions, so I don't really want to hold any substantial thing in memory.

Comment: Have you tried it?  Sequence expressions are "lazy" for that exact reason; they only load the next item into memory when that item is requested for something concrete.  So you can even have infinite sequences with no memory problems.  Try it and profile it to see what's happening.

Comment: But if I iterate over the whole thing, doesn't the whole thing eventually get loaded up?

Comment: No, the GC should collect the things you're done using.

Comment: Sequences you can use for a custom logical enumeration of your items, say a tree in-order, pre-order and post-order. That said, they only hide your enumeration state and do so quite efficiently. Whe you have an operation that anyhow involves disk IO, sequences will be fast enough be at least several orders of magnitude.The only thing to keep in mind, that they are **not** cached, so enumerating multiple times causes multiple enumeration of the underlaying data source.

Comment: @Petr +1 for your comment, but I believe you meant to say "initialized" rather than "instantiated"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are only a very few cases where you would actually need this in F#. Most likely, you can find another (more functional and more idiomatic) way of doing this.

For example, in C# you might often need to declare a variable for scope purposes if you want to initialize it using `if`:

```
int some;  
if (Condition()) { some = 1; }
else { Console.WriteLine("yay"); some = 2; }
```

But you don't need to do this in F#, because `if` is an expression:

```
let some = 
  if Condition() then 1
  else
    Console.WriteLine("yay")
    2
```

So, if you describe the concrete situation you are facing, you will probably get a more useful answer with a nicer idiomatic F# solution.

Answer (score 3):

Values in F# are immutable, so there is no ability to change the value. Thus there is no means to do what you want directly.

Rather one would normally create a "[ref cell](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx)" – a container for a variable – which does allow the content of the value to be changed. However you will still need to initialise the cell. (See the link for an example.)

Better would be to refactor the code to avoid the need (not always possible, but F# has sufficient syntax that this is possible far more than in imperative languages like C#).